# Como obter o offset de um timezone (exemplo: "America/Sao_Paulo" resulta em "-3")

Tags: php, data, timezone

Eu recebo variáveis de timezone em formato de região, ex: `America/Sao_Paulo`.

Tem como transformá-la na diferença de horário em relação a UTC? No caso seria `-3` ou `-03:00`.

Comment: Trabalhar com horas é algo complexo e sem contexto qualquer resposta pode ser suposição do entendimento do problema, existe grandes changes da pergunta ser um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635). É importante **[edit] e reformular a pergunta seguindo exatamente as orientações em: [mcve] e explicar de forma clara e objetiva**. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Comment: Bruno, acho que o que ajudaria muito seria deixar claro se você recebe de fato uma string "America/Sao_Paulo" em texto mesmo, ou se já está deduzindo isso com base em outra informação. Tem uma resposta detalhada se for esse o caso, mas com base nessa suposição (e que corre o risco de não ser bem isso que quer, ou de ser EXATAMENTE o caso) - Se puder editar e confirmar/detalhar ajuda muito.

Comment: Bruno, pra complementar, no Brasil temos 4 zonas horárias diferentes ([UTC -5: Acre Time; UTC -4: Amazon Time; UTC -3: Brasília Time; UTC -2: Fernando de Noronha Time](/a/417492/3635)), não tem como afirmar que um horário recebido de fato é -3 (ou -03:00), então tratar isso do lado do PHP pode não resolver o problema, ao contrário, criará mais problemas (isso é o problema XY que citei), o ideal seria repensar em como receber esse valor (provavelmente do front-end), aqui explico alguns problemas de forma ilustrada: [problema mais comum](/a/319413/3635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de dar a solução, tem um detalhe importante a se considerar:

## Nem sempre é `-3`

Timezones como `America/Sao_Paulo` são definidos pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), e segundo a [documentação deles](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html), um timezone representa o **histórico de *offsets*** que determinada região teve ao longo do tempo. Ou seja, não necessariamente será apenas um único valor.

No caso de `America/Sao_Paulo`, existem vários períodos em que teve horário de verão, no qual o *offset* muda para `-2`.

Atualmente (janeiro de 2023) não tem horário de verão, mas lembre-se que isso é definido pelo governo, e historicamente é algo que vive mudando (não só no Brasil, mas [no mundo todo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/)). Pode ser que volte, pode ser que resolvam mudar para outro porque sim, a única certeza que temos é que não dá pra ter certeza de que sempre será assim. Só porque hoje é `-3`, nada garante que continuará assim pra sempre.

Ou seja, além do identificador do timezone, você **sempre** precisa de uma data de referência. Em determinada data, o *offset* de um timezone tem um valor. Em outra data, pode ou não ter o mesmo valor.

Claro que no caso de `America/Sao_Paulo`, para a maioria dos casos vai ser `-3`, mas ainda sim, não dá pra assumir que *sempre* é. Você precisa informar uma data, porque pode ser que esteja em horário de verão. E dependendo do timezone, pode ser um *offset* completamente diferente (existem países que simplesmente decidem mudar seu *offset* "em definitivo" - exemplos: [1](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2018/05/04/the-brief-history-of-north-koreas-time-zone/), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Samoa#2011_time_zone_change)).

---

Enfim, sabendo disso, uma solução é primeiro criar um [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) e em seguida usar o [método `getOffset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) passando a data como argumento. O detalhe é que este método retorna o *offset* em segundos, então para saber a quantidade de horas precisa dividir por 3600:

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');

// data atual - provavelmente -3, ***a não ser que o horário de verão volte***
// aí pode ser -3 ou -2 dependendo da data
echo $tz->getOffset(new DateTime()) / 3600; // -3
// uma data que com certeza está no horário de verão
echo $tz->getOffset(new DateTime('2000-01-10T10:00Z')) / 3600; // -2
```

Também dá para criar a data e obter o *offset* diretamente dela:

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');

// data atual
$d = new DateTime('now', $tz);
echo $d->getOffset() / 3600; // -3 (ou -2 se a data atual estiver em horário de verão)

// data em horário de verão
$d = new DateTime('2000-01-10T10:00', $tz);
echo $d->getOffset() / 3600; // -2
```

Mas se quiser no formato `-03:00`, aí precisa formatar a data:

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');

// data atual
$d = new DateTime('now', $tz);
echo $d->format('P'); // -03:00 (ou -02:00 se a data atual estiver em horário de verão)

// data em horário de verão
$d = new DateTime('2000-01-10T10:00', $tz);
echo $d->format('P'); // -02:00
```

---

Vale lembrar também que nem todo *offset* é de "hora cheia". Por exemplo, na Índia, atualmente o *offset* é `+05:30` (5 horas e meia à frente do UTC). Ou seja, a primeira solução (dividir por 3600) vai dar um valor quebrado (e neste caso, acho que seria mais claro usar o valor formatado):

```php
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
$d = new DateTime('2000-01-10T10:00', $tz);
echo $d->getOffset() / 3600; // 5.5
echo $d->format('P'); // +05:30
```

---

Lembrando que, como essas informações de timezone mudam o tempo todo, o banco de dados da IANA está em constante mudança, e novas versões são anunciadas [aqui](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/).

No caso do PHP, você pode atualizar a [extensão `timezonedb`](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb), já que esta é sincronizada com as atualizações da IANA.

Comment: Isso funcionou perfeitamente. E a explicação foi bem esclarecedora.
Obrigado!